# Will JSX conditional rendering out of an object code split?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Will conditional rendering out of an object code split and lazy load as expected?  Here's a short example of what I'm talking about.

```
const Component1 = lazy(() => import('some path'));
const Component2 = lazy(() => import('some path'));
const Component3 = lazy(() => import('some path'));

render () {
  const { selectionIndex } = this.state;
  <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    {{
      one: <Component1 />,
      two: <Component2 />,
      three: <Component3 />,
    }[selectionIndex]}
  </Suspense>
}
```

I want to know whether all three components will load on render, or just the one selected by selectionIndex.  I'm trying to use this to conditionally select something to display based on a menu set by state, but I don't want to load everything at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will not get rendered all at once. You can experiment by yourself, put `console.log` inside components is an easy way to find out.

React for web consists of two libs, "react" and "react-dom". "react" is in charge of encapsulating your logic intention into declarative data structures, while "react-dom" consumes these data structures and handles the actual "rendering" part of job.

The JSX element creation syntax `<Component {…props} />` translates to plain JS as an API call to `React.createElement(Component, props)`. The return value of this API call is actually just a plain object of certain shape that roughly looks like:

```js
{
  type: Component,
  props: props
}
```

This is the aforementioned "declarative data structure". You can inspect it in console.

As you can see, calling `React.createElement` just return such data structure, it will not directly call the `.render()` method or functional component’s function body. The data structure is submitted to "react-dom" lib to be eventually "rendered".

So your example code just create those data structures, but the related component will not be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

seems like its conditionally loaded based on selectionIndex. all the other components are not loaded at once.

P.S.: if you ever feel like which will get load first, just put a console log in that component and debug easily

[conditionally load demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lazy-load-conditional-load-cgmew?file=/src/App.js) - if you open this, the components are being loaded initially based on selectionIndex value being "one".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go into too much technical detail, because I feel like @hackape already provided you with a great answer as to why, point of my answer is just to explain how *(to check it)*

In general, I'd recommend you to download download the **React Developer Tools**

- [chrome link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)
- [firefox link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/)

and then you can check which components are being rendered if you open the components tab inside your developer console. Here's a sandboxed example, best way to find out is to test it yourself afterall :-)

[image]

[image: Edit sleepy-ardinghelli-c0scu]

As you can see in the developer tools *(bottom right)*, only the currently set element is being rendered